# Django: create dynamic attributes related to objects

Tags: django, django-models

In my models I have a few "masterdata" models. These contain the most relevant / standardized values.

For different purposes I need different "attributes" / "variables" related to these master data.

I dont want to create a variable for each possibility in the master model.

Say e.g. I have the model Material. It will contains some basic variables.

My rationale is to have a seperate model, Material_Attributes. This would contain a foreign key to Material, and allow for example to store attribute "packing" with value "cartons".

At the model I'm a bit in doubt whether these attributes and options should be stored in a third model.

But in this case, it would relate to Material only. I might also want to store an attribute to objects from model Customers.

I could build the same logic, but it would be rather static (need to do for each model), or perhaps I can do a work around with GenericForeignKeys to allow even the model to be dynamic.

Anybody encountered something similar in the past, and how to go about?

I'm a bit struggling how to go about. What would be a logic step to go about?

Example:

```
class Person(models.Model): 
    first_name = models.CharField(max_length=30)
    last_name = models.CharField(max_length=30)
    profession = models.CharField(max_length=30)
```

Or, as below, where I could store attribute profession with a value, and maybe later, for a subset I might need to add height, or gender. This would allow me to add attributed without changing the Model.

```
class Person(models.Model): 
    first_name = models.CharField(max_length=30)
    last_name = models.CharField(max_length=30)

class Person_Attribute(models.Model):
    person = models.ForeignKey(Person, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    attribute = models.CharField(max_length=30)
    attribute_val = models.CharField(max_length=30)
```

Comment: Please add code example reading long paragrahs will get you no help.